# Run codenarc inspection in realtime in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, inspection, codenarc

Is there any way to run inspections in real time in intellij, rather than just having to select `Analyze > Inspect Code`. In particular, I'd like to do real time codenarc analysis (similar to how Eclipse does with checkstyle) so when I save a file it tells me if there are violations. I downloaded the codenarc plugin, but it doesn't seem to support that explicitly.

Comment: I think there is no way of properly doing that even with `Analyze > Inspect Code`. I see neither a way of using custom rules configuration nor the tool version up to date. Am I mistaken?

Answer (score 3):

If you go to settings -> inspections, you will see there is a bunch of CodeNarc entries that you can tick.

I recommend creating a separate inspection profile if you use CodeNarc in a Continuous Integration tool, so you can focus on violations that would break the build.

Now it is true that you have to analyze the code explicitly the first time, but then it happens on the fly, and by right clicking you can also disable a given inspection or re-run it on other parts of your code.

Comment: This does not work with CodeNarc Updated 4.2.1.